# When changing keyboard input language, I want to change the font size too

Tags: macos, keyboard, notes.app, internationalization, language

I take notes (in Notes mainly) in both English and Korean, so I switch keyboard input language frequently.  A font size of 13 is good for english, but the Korean characters are more readable with a font size of 18.

So when I switch to Korean, I frequently press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> 5 times to get the font size up to 18.  Or I keep the font window open and click on 18 or 13 depending on my language.  I also use Bettertouchtool with a macro to merge the five 'increase font size' commands, assigned to a 2 finger touchpad double tap.  Still a little awkward though.

Was just wondering if anybody knew how to make a default font size for each input language?  Even if it's a utility.  The idea would be when I use Caps Lock or fn to change keyboard languages, the font size would change as well.